# Is this intended to be a sign that Uesugi is socially awkward?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets

At around 11:30 in Episode 6 of *5-toubun no Hanayome ∬*, Ichika offers to buy books for Uesugi. Uesugi just waits outside the store while Ichika is paying the check, then, when Ichika is done paying and go home with Uesugi, it's Ichika who carry the books on their way back home even though her hand's hurt. All the work here is done by Ichika alone and yet for Uesugi.

Is it the etiquette in Japan not to wait in line while your friend is paying in a store? You know, Uesugi could have been talking with Ichika while she's queueing and paying the money. Is this intended to be a sign that Uesugi is socially awkward?

Uesugi waiting outside:
[image]

Ichika carrying the bag and Uesugi putting both his hands in the pocket in a leisurely manner:
[image]

Comment: There are 2 Uesugi's. You might want to use 1st names. You wouldn't call any of the quints Nakano would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. It doesn't go like this at all in the manga.

---

## Manga answer:

From Ch58:

[image]

Fuutarou just waits inside the store but is asked to do so by Ichika.

---

## Anime answer:

Ichika probably told Fuutarou to just wait outside. Idk. Wait... I think I get it: Maybe it's about privacy.

From an earlier scene in S02E06:

[image]

It's actually clearer I think in Ch58:

[image]

Ichika probably didn't want Fuutarou to see how much cash or savings or whatever Ichika/the quints still had. It doesn't matter whether Fuutarou waits inside or still in the store. In fact to really ensure privacy, waiting outside is probably better.

---

## For both cases:

You might say Fuutarou should insist 'I'll go with you or something', but I think that suggests some kind of intimacy. Besides Ichika is the 1 paying, so I guess Ichika gets to decide.

Or maybe... AU CONTRAIRE it shows how socially sharp Fuutarou is! Fuutarou maybe should insist, but Fuutarou might realise 'Oh, Ichika probably doesn't want me to see how much cash they have left' or something. Yeah! Remember in the previous episode S02E05

[image]

Ichika tells them they're running out of savings.

Wow that was a fun exercise. It turns out not only is Fuutarou not socially awkward but actually that Fuutarou is pretty socially sharp!